# Whats a good method to find and cleanup unused methods in a WCF service?

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm having a lot methods in a couple of WCF services and I want to remove the unused ones. Searching through code one method at a time requires to much time so... What's the best way to do that?
I'm thinking like some kind of interceptor to tell me the names of the methods being called while testing the application, I don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a code coverage tool for this. There are several for .NET, one of which I'm currently evaluating, but I'm not prepared to give a recommendation just yet :)

Comment: That's a good idea, but the methods are called from different applications outside the services solution. I don't think a code coverage tool will work, but thanks anyway.

Comment: "...methods are called from different applications outside the services solution" That should not be a problem.